# The role of the extraction matrix in a Kalman filter

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-complexity, bayesian-network, kalman-filter

The extraction matrix shown as $H_k$ below, transforms the state vector into a form that can be subtracted from the measurements vector:

$\hat{X}_k = \hat{X}_k^- + K_k ({z}_k - H_k \hat{X}_k^-)$

Where $\hat{X}_k^-$ is the projected state (from the state transition model), ${z}_k$ is the measurement vector, and $K_k$ is the Kalman gain.

Why is the filter normally formed in this way? Right now $\hat{X}_k^-$ is being transformed to the "measurement space" (for lack of a better term) and subtracted from the measurement vector, then it is transformed back into the "state space" by being multiplied by $K_k$. Why don't we just transform the measurement matrix instead so that we'd deal with only one transformation?

Is there any benefit in doing it this way?

Thanks!

EDIT: let me explain this better.
I'm proposing to modify the measurement update process so it would be of this form: $\hat{X}_k = \hat{X}_k^- + L_k(G_kz_k - \hat{X}_k^-)$. I feel this would be less computationally taxing. The end result would be the same. Instead of multiplying $\hat{X}_k^-$ by $H_k$ I am multiplying $z_k$ by $G_k$. $L_k$ would be the Kalman gain after it has been modified to be compatible with these changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out. The use of the extraction matrix in the conventional way allows for multi-sensor fusion, i.e. more than one sensor measuring each state variable.

For example if $z_1$ and $z_2$ are two measurements for the state variables one can form a measurement vector:

$Z = \begin{bmatrix} z_1 \\ z_2 \end{bmatrix} $

And the state variable is:

$ X = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{bmatrix} $

The extraction matrix would be such that $X$ would be converted into a vector that can be subtracted from $Z$:

$H = \begin{bmatrix} h_{11} & h_{12} & h_{13} \\ h_{21} & h_{22} & h_{23} \end{bmatrix} $

In this situation, the Kalman gain would provide an optimal solution based on both measurements. What I was proposing in the original question would cause problems here.